# Adding bluetooth dongle to vmware server

Tags: virtual-machines, bluetooth

I need to test some bluetooth code using a VM. Im wondering how to setup the VM (and thus the server) with a bt dongle to access my device.

If I simply plug the bt dongle into the server running my VM will VMWare understand what to do  next? Or will this bollux up other VMs running on this machine?

Comment: How does the Bluetooth dongle connect? What VMware hypervisor/product are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware's server and vSphere products support some USB 1.1 functionality for the VM guest OS(s). If the dongle requires USB 2 features, you might have problems.

You will need to explicitly configure the USB device to be assigned/allocated to the VM in question. If your Host OS takes hold of the device, then it will prevent proper operation with the Guest VM. Same story if you fire up a new VM and it includes the USB suport, it may also take the USB device.